# How come the expression "Tout ce qu'elle voudra !" can even be directed at a man, not a woman?

Tags: expressions

I just heard in conversation:

> César: Remettons nous au travail. Et plus vite que ça.
>
> Another colleague: Bien sûr, César ! **Tout ce qu'elle voudra !**

I assume this expression is similar to "à vos ordres". The thing is that one of my colleagues, César, is male through and through, so I wonder why the pronoun "elle" was directed at him, instead of "il"?

Comment: Is it perhaps a direct quote from a play or something? In English one says (whether sagely or no) "The lady doth protest too much" with fair disregard for context.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Or [a song](http://fr.lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Les_Chats_Sauvages/Tout_ce_qu%27elle_voudra)?

Answer (score 2):

The pronoun “elle” may refer to “Sa Majesté” (“His Highness” in English), especially when talking to César!

Comment: But....César is his coworker, not actually César.

Comment: This may be ironic. What's the context ?